# How to find equation for categorizing objects?

Tags: functions

I have a problem and I need to find a function to categorize element, I'm an expert in math that's why I need the help of the community.

the problem is as follows, I have a set of cars that have these attributes like the model year, mileage traveled, fuel type, fuel consumed per 100km, price. however, we can add more attributes if we need to.

base on these attributes I want to calculate a score of these cars :

```
object car1 = {
  model year = 2016, 
  mileage traveled = 100000, 
  fuel type = D, 
  fuel consumed per 100km = 5, 
  price = 2500
}
object car2 = {
  model year = 2016, 
  mileage traveled = 150000, 
  fuel type = D, 
  fuel consumed per 100km = 7.1, 
  price = 2400
}

score1 = function(car1);
score2 = function(car2);
```

I want a fitness function which takes these attributes and calculate the scores, based on the score I will be able to categorize these set of cars.

Comment: Not sure what the question is.  You can invent any score you like.  Surely that choice is a purely subjective matter.  Did you have some properties you wanted your score to satisfy?  That might narrow things down a bit.

Comment: I'm looking for some kind of fitness function, I did not what are these things to narrow down

Comment: Again, "fitness" isn't a defined term (unless you define it).  Even if you say in a general way that you prefer newer cars to old, fuel efficient cars over gas guzzlers, etc., there is no obvious way to choose between attributes.  How many years of age is comparable to an extra mile per gallon?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I have asked the question, to find a definition of this equation.

Comment: As I say, the matter is purely subjective.  Maybe I prefer cars made in $1968$ to all other cars.  Maybe you disagree.  It's not a matter of right and wrong.  There simply isn't a math problem here.